# Focus Combobox of custom GridCellEditor on Begin Edit

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm creating a custom GridCellEditor for being able to use levenshtein algorithm and suggest strings depending on the entered value of the user.

```
class GridCellLevenshteinEditor(wx.grid.PyGridCellEditor):

    """A Grid Cell Editor with a combobox that offers choices sorted
    with the levenshtein algorithm."""

    def __init__(self, choices, allow_new_entries=False):
        wx.grid.PyGridCellEditor.__init__(self)
        # this holds all the possible strings, that can be selected
        self.choices = choices
        self.allow_new_entries = allow_new_entries

        self.start_value = None
        self.combobox = None

    def Create(self, parent, id, evt_handler):
        """Creates the actual edit control."""
        self.combobox = ComboBox(parent, None, self.choices, doSort=False,
                                 style=wx.CB_SIMPLE)
        self.SetControl(self.combobox)
        if evt_handler:
            self.combobox.PushEventHandler(evt_handler)

    def BeginEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        """Fetch the value from the table and prepare the edit control
        to begin editing.
        This function should save the original value of the grid cell at the
        given row and col and show the control allowing the user to
        change it."""
        self.start_value = grid.GetTable().GetValue(row, col)
        if self.start_value in ("", None):
            self.start_value = "test"
        self.combobox.ChangeValue(self.start_value)
        self.combobox.SetFocus()  # <-- this causes an issue

    def set_new_choices(self, new_choices):
        """Empties the Combobox Control and fills it with the new given
        choices. Can be used as well for example for updating the choices."""
        self.choices = new_choices
        self.combobox.refresh_combo_box(new_choices, False)
```

Without `self.combobox.SetFocus()` this looks like this in a Grid:

[image: LevenshteinEditor without Focus]

Now I want the text field of the ComboBox, where the user can type, automatically focused when the edit begins. So I added `self.combobox.SetFocus()`, but this is causing only troubles. The dropdown of the ComboBox will be shown for a few milliseconds and then closes again and then the edit process has ended automatically. Means I would have to click in the cell again to start the edit process again, though this will be ended immediately again by itself, because of the SetFocus().

Does anyone know how to let the user entered text be automatically selected on starting the edit process of a grid cell, without the combobox acting in a weird way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Combo-box-as-grid-cell-editor-td2360176.html

When I changed the focus the default event handler thought that I finished editing and called EndEdit(). Because of that I had to override the event handling for my combobox editor by adding a `PushEventHandler(wx.EvtHandler())`.

So I had to change following methods.

```
def Create(self, parent, dummy_id, dummy_evt_handler):
"""Creates the actual edit control."""
    self.combobox = ComboBox(parent, None, self.choices, doSort=False,
                             style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
    self.SetControl(self.combobox)
    self.combobox.PushEventHandler(wx.EvtHandler())
    self.combobox.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.process_enter,
                       self.combobox)

def process_enter(self, dummy_event):
    """This gets called, when the enter key was pressed in the combobox."""
    # end edit and select next cell
    self.grid.DisableCellEditControl()
    self.grid.MoveCursorRight(False)

def BeginEdit(self, row, col, grid):
    """Fetch the value from the table and prepare the edit control
    to begin editing.
    This function should save the original value of the grid cell at the
    given row and col and show the control allowing the user to
    change it."""
    self.grid = grid
    self.start_value = grid.GetTable().GetValue(row, col)
    self.combobox.ChangeValue(self.start_value)
    self.combobox.SetFocus()
```